# Is it possible to deploy a Rust project to the apt package manager?

Tags: linux, rust, apt, package-managers

I want to deploy my CLI project which I reacted in Rust to the apt package manager so it can be installed by anyone, but I could not find the proper documentation on how to do it.

I tried to upload it via cargo.io, but they do not have any direct support for terminal based package managers.

Comment: it obviously concern the package manager you try to use, this is in no way about cargo or rust.

Comment: *"via cargo.io, but they do not have any direct support for terminal based package managers"* - I guess you mean *crates.io*, and this **is** in my opinion actually the correct way. It's just not `apt`, but `cargo` that you need to install it. `cargo` **is** in fact a terminal based package manager; you can type `cargo install <your-package-name>` to install the program to your computer. This is Rust's way of making it "installable by anyone".